# How to fetch multiple row value which contains multiple value separated by comma into a single array in php using pdo mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database table name books. Now I need to fetch value from multiple row values (column name position) which contains multiple value separated by comma. Now I need to fetch values from multiple rows into an array using pdo php.

[image]

```
<?php
require_once "includes\config.php";

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE shelf_no=2';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchALl(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$d = array();
foreach ($row as $value) {
$d[] = explode(",",$value['position']);
}

print_r($d);
?>
```

and the result is

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [0] => b1 
    [1] => b2 
  ) 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [0] => a2 
    [1] => a3
  )
)
```

But I need all values in a single array, like this:

```
Array ( [0] => b1 [1] => b2 [2] => a2 [3] => a3 )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Make sure to include code you have already tried and what errors you are getting.

Comment: @Second2None pls give me a suggestion

Comment: Storing delimited data in a relational database column is a bad idea. You should ideally redesign your tables to support a _many-to-many_ relationship. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Comment: _"i need all values in a single array"_  what does this mean? Can you show an example of what you'd like the result to be?

Comment: Array ( 
    [0] => b1 
    [1] => b2  
    [2] => a2 
    [3] => a3
  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exploding it (creating a new array) and then adding that array to another array.

You could run through each value in the exploded string and add them:

```
<?php
require_once "includes\config.php";

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE shelf_no=2';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchALl(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$d = array();
foreach ($row as $value) {
    $temp = explode(",",$value['position']);
    foreach($temp as $pos){
        array_push($d, trim($pos));
    }   
}

print_r($d);
?>
```

If there are duplicates they will show though.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I get what i need. @Second2None

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace your

```
$d[] = explode(",",$value['position']);
```

with

```
array_merge($d, explode(',', $value['position']));
```

That will make one array rather than an array of arrays.  More info on [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) at php.net.

A lot of PHP functions are more performant than the equivalent written in PHP.  I.e. this may be faster than a nested `foreach` loop.  As always, if this is important to you, time both ways.